# Telethon how to print error messages inside an async method?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, telethon

How to print an error messages that occurs inside an async method?

@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def my_event_handler(event):

In my case it gets completely ignored. I suppose it has something to do with async method.
Is there a simple way to enable error messages in development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import logging
import tracemalloc
tracemalloc.start()
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',
                    level=logging.WARN)
```

Comment: Link to the docs: https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/basic/updates.html